# How to generate xml report with maven depencency?

Tags: java, xml, maven, reporting, pom.xml

I would like to use the command `mvn dependency:analyze-report` to generate xml report.
Actually the report generated is html format.
The plug-in declaration :

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.8</version>
  <configuration>
    <outputXML>true</outputXML>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

The `outputXML` is not a valid option for the `analyze-report` goal ([see here for supported options](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-report-mojo.html)).

Perhaps you meant to execute `mvn dependency:analyze`, which does allow that option to be specified: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html#outputXML.